# Python Telnet connection using Exscript

Tags: python, telnet, python-2.6

I am trying to connect to a Cisco Firewall using this code:

```
 from Exscript.util.interact import read_login
 from Exscript.protocols import Telnet

 cmd = "?"
 conn = Telnet()
 conn.connect('10.60.2.254')

 conn.get_password_prompt()
 conn.send('password')
 conn.execute(cmd)
 print conn.response
 conn.send('exit\r')               
 conn.close()
```

but i am getting this error:

```
File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__

File "C:\Users\blablabla\Desktop\ciscopytest.py", line 13, in <module>
    conn.execute(cmd)

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\exscript-development-py2.6.egg\Exscript\protocols\Protocol.py", line 888, in execute
    return self.expect_prompt()

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\exscript-development-py2.6.egg\Exscript\protocols\Protocol.py", line 987, in expect_prompt
    result = self.expect(self.get_prompt())

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\exscript-development-py2.6.egg\Exscript\protocols\Protocol.py", line 968, in expect
    result = self._expect(prompt)

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\exscript-development-py2.6.egg\Exscript\protocols\Protocol.py", line 944, in _expect
    result = self._domatch(to_regexs(prompt), True)

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\exscript-development-py2.6.egg\Exscript\protocols\Telnet.py", line 85, in _domatch
    raise TimeoutException(error)

TimeoutException: Error while waiting for response from device
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because `?` is not an actual command. It displays help without explicitly pressing Enter.

Try the following, instead of `conn.execute(cmd)`:

```
conn.send(cmd)
self.expect_prompt()
```

If this does not work, please paste the output of the device when you manually press `?`

Comment: i replaced the cmd with `show version` and i get the same error. i've tried with execute and send and the error persists

Comment: if i just use conn.send('?') i get **User Access Verification
Password: 
Type help or '?' for a list of available commands.** this is the login screen after the first authentication but the command `?` is not showing. it should display `
  clear       Reset functions
  enable      Turn on privileged commands
  exit        Exit from the EXEC
  help        Interactive help for commands
  login       Log in as a particular user
  logout      Exit from the EXEC
  ...`